# objectbox inheritance using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, objectbox

[The ObjectBox documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/entity-inheritance) gives some examples of how you can use inheritance. However it gives the example in Java and not Kotlin. The [Kotlin examples](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started) it does give use Kotlin data classes, which as I understand it, don't support inheritance. Is it possible in object box, and if so can you point to an example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if possible and in most cases inheritance should not be used with entity classes.

If it absolutely has to happen, it is possible to mirror the Java example in Kotlin by using regular Kotlin classes vs. Kotlin data classes. There is no restriction on using data classes only.

For example this should work:

```
// Superclass:
@BaseEntity
abstract class Base {
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0
    var baseString: String? = null

    constructor()
    constructor(id: Long, baseString: String?) {
        this.id = id
        this.baseString = baseString
    }
}

// Subclass:
@Entity
class Sub : Base {
    var subString: String? = null

    constructor()
    constructor(id: Long, baseString: String?, subString: String?) : super(id, baseString) {
        this.subString = subString
    }
}
```

Comment: Added Kotlin examples to the docs: https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/entity-inheritance

Comment: Thanks. Why should inheritance not be used?

Comment: It makes things unnecessary complicated. Using data classes ensures an entity is self-contained and mirrors database behavior (e.g. there is no such thing as inheritance).

Comment: Ok. Understood. I'm not seeing these nosql databases going anywhere if they can't offer something more tangible over SQL databases, especially in terms of mirroring your in memory model. Frankly I don't get why object databases aren't winning.